# Como detectar se o usuario esta acessando por um app webview

Tags: javascript, html, android, css, webview

Olá, criei um app webview para meu site pois ele é 100% responsivo e se adapta bem nos aparelhos mobile, mas no meu menu tem um link para vc baixar este aplicativo, gostaria de saber como posso identificar um acesso webview pois quero ocultar este menu quando utilizam o app webview.

Ex: [image: Menu do meu website]

Aonde está MUFLIX PLAY, gostaria de ocultar quando acessado através da webview :P

Comment: Pela largura da tela não serve? Talvez do lado servidor através do `$_SERVER ["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]` (php)

Comment: mas e quem acessa pelo navegador do celular ? queria identificar quando e webview e quando e navegador pra criar um css personalizado :(

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam existem navegadores com a opção de mudar o user agent

Answer (score -1):

Normalmente, para detectar se um usuário está acessando a página em uma *iframe*, com JavaScript, usa-se [`window.top`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_top.asp) para checar se é igual ao `window` atual. Ou seja, se `window !== window.top` for `true`, então o usuário tá em um *iframe*. Será que isso também não funciona no seu caso? E se for feito, por exemplo, no JavaScript:

```
// Se estiver em um iframe...
if (window !== window.top) {

  // Adicionar a class "webview" no body...
  document.body.classList.add("webview");
}
```

...e no CSS:

```
body.webview {
  /* Estilo aqui... */
}
```

Comment: vou dar uma olhada aqui :)